# How to make dim background when tap on 1 uiimageview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have 1 tabelview,  add 4 imageviews in cell. When user tap on any imageview, the background will be dim and the imageview just selected will be bring on top of the dim view.

I tried this code :

```
self.dimView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

self.dimView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.dimView.alpha = 0.7;
self.dimView.hidden = YES;
[self.sellItemtbl addSubview:self.dimView];
//[self.view bringSubviewToFront:dimView];

//add tap gesture to dimview
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.dimView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

But it only create 1 dim view, and the image just selected cannot bring on top of this view. How can i do that? Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is `self.sellItemtbl`? It will help to know what you are adding `self.dimView` to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear by background did you mean only your table view cell or the entire view. I have assumed it to be only table view cell and enclosing you the code of table view cell. You can extend it to entire view by making use of `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:1.f]];

    [self.imgView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imgView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imgView3 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imgView4 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self.imgView1 setTag:1];
    [self.imgView2 setTag:2];
    [self.imgView3 setTag:3];
    [self.imgView4 setTag:4];

    [self.imgView1 addGestureRecognizer:[self getTapGestureRecognizer]];
    [self.imgView2 addGestureRecognizer:[self getTapGestureRecognizer]];
    [self.imgView3 addGestureRecognizer:[self getTapGestureRecognizer]];
    [self.imgView4 addGestureRecognizer:[self getTapGestureRecognizer]];
}

- (UITapGestureRecognizer *)getTapGestureRecognizer
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMade:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    return tapGesture;
}

- (void)tapMade:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;
    NSInteger tag = imgView.tag;

    [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.7f]];
    [self.imgView1 setAlpha:(tag == 1)? 1.f: 0.7f];
    [self.imgView2 setAlpha:(tag == 2)? 1.f: 0.7f];
    [self.imgView3 setAlpha:(tag == 3)? 1.f: 0.7f];
    [self.imgView4 setAlpha:(tag == 4)? 1.f: 0.7f];
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.